# Laravel 6 decrypt old encrypted links from Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-6

I am relatively new to Laravel and I have been trying to migrate an Application running on Laravel 4.2 to Laravel 6. I have managed to get it working with a few exceptions.

We have a lot of old emails sent with various links and these are encrypted I believe using the old deprecated Mcrypt. I understand Laravel 6 uses the OpenSSL new cipher for encryption.

I am not completely aware of how this functionality works. Is there a way the new App can read the older links. Do I need to process the old links with the old type of decipher.

Any advice is much appreciated